# validate the input value using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Let say i got input text and dropdown option. As default the dropdown is disabled and input is enabled. So employee id input is playing a role as validate the value that have been key in. Actually the employee id input is where user scan their employeed id where the lenght is equal to 6 and the drowpdown will be enabled. Another method to bypass the scanning the employee id, certain employee will key in specific Keywords at the input for example "KYXY", and by insert the keyword they able to key in the input employee id manually and once employee id input manually length==6 and the dropdown will enabled.. For me this abit tricky.

```
<input type="text" id="myContent" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Staff ID">

<select class="form-control" id="dropdownss" disabled="" value="Disabled value">
<option>Select Shift</option>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>
```

So here is my jquery

```
$('document').ready(function() {
        $('#myContent').keyup('input',function(){
        var a = "KYXY";
        var myNumber = this.value;

        if(myNumber == a)
        {
        $('#dropdownss').prop( "disabled", false );
        $('#myContent').val('');
        var userlog="1";


            if($(this).val().length == 6)
            {
                if(userlog == "1")
                {
                    //alert("Yay");
                    $('#myContent').val('');
                    $('#myContent').focus();
                    $('#dropdownss').prop( "disabled", false );
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#dropdownss').prop( "disabled", true );
                }
            }
        }
        else if(myNumber !== a)
        {
            alert("scan only");
            $('#myContent').val('');
            $('#myContent').focus();
        }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: If the user is manually entering the value (not copying/pasting the entire KYXY value into the box it will clear out and give the scan only message as soon as they key anything.

Comment: Is the KYXY code supposed to be like a "manager override" that your typical employee shouldn't be able to enter or see?  If so you may want to do some sort of server-side validation vs presenting it in clear text here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#myContent').on('input', function() {
    var a = "KYXY";
    var input = $(this);
    var num = input.val();
    
    if (num.length === 6 && !/\D/.test(num)) { 
      $('#dropdownss').prop("disabled", false);
      input.prop('manual', false).val('');
    }
    else if (input.prop('manual') || ~a.indexOf(num)) {
      if (a !== input.val()) return;
      input.prop('manual', true).val('');      
    } else {
      alert("scan only");
      $('#dropdownss').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#myContent').val('');
      $('#myContent').focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myContent" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Staff ID">

<select class="form-control" id="dropdownss" disabled="" value="Disabled value">
  <option>Select Shift</option>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Seems like this would be really easy to abuse if a regular employee having access to it would be an issue.  Though, obviously doing this client-side makes this a moot point anyway.

Comment: it works well after edit some of the code. Just dont know !/\D/.test(num), input.prop('manual'), and ~a.indexOf(num) for.

Comment: @NathanChampion not regular employee have the access. just certain have privilage to access the part with such keyword for testing purpose instead of scan.

Answer (score 0):

I had to rewrite a big part of your jQuery code. But this should work.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var myContent =  $('#myContent');
    var dropdown = $('#dropdownss');

    myContent.on('keyup', function() {
        var a = "KYXY";
        var myNumber = $(this).val();

        if (myNumber ==  a) {
            dropdown.removeAttr("disabled");
            myContent.val('');

            var userlog = "1";

            if ($(this).val().length == 6) {
                if (userlog == "1") {
                    // Alert("Yay");
                    myContent.val('');
                    myContent.focus();
                    dropdown.removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    dropdown.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        } else if (myNumber.length >= 6 && myNumber != a) {
            alert("Scan only");
            myContent.val('');
            myContent.focus();
        }
    });
});
```